# Bash Script to append for specific file extensions in a directory

Tags: sed

How do I prepends a special character in front of all the lines in all .txt files in my directory? Im new to writing bash scripts and having trouble doing this. I only know of using the grep function but thats only to search for keyword.

For now, I have this,

```
sed -i 's/^/#/' Machine1.txt
```

However, this is only for that specific .txt file. I want to do this for all files with a .txt extension in my directory. There are other extensions like .tar, .rpm, .sh files which I want to ignore. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Just give a wildcard filename argument.

```
sed -i 's/^/#/' *.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use for loop.
For example

```
cd your_folder 
for f in *.txt; do 
  sed -i 's/^/#/' "$f";
done
```

Comment: They said just `.txt` files.